# Youtube Data API v3 - How to insert a video using Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to create a project in Flutter where I can record videos with my phone and upload them directly to my YouTube account using the `videos.insert` method from YouTube Data API. I managed to get all the required authentifications and have access to the YouTube Data API (I tested it with other API calls and it worked without any issues) but I am stuck with `videos.insert` method.

Here is my code so far:

```
    Video video = new Video();
    video.snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    video.snippet!.title = "Default Video Title";
    video.snippet!.description = "Default Video Description";
    video.snippet!.tags = ["tag1", "tag2" ];
    video.snippet!.categoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    video.status = new VideoStatus();
    video.status!.privacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
    var filePath = ""; // Replace with path to actual movie file.
    var stream = new File(filePath).readAsString();

    var httpClient = (await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient())!;
    var youTubeApi = YouTubeApi(httpClient);

    var videosInsertRequest = youTubeApi.videos.insert(video, ["snippet", "status"]);
```

I couldn't find any examples of Dart code on Google and I am new to programming in Dart/Flutter - how should I read the video file and where do I need to insert it in my code for the request to be completed? if I try to add my `stream` or `filePath` variable as another parameter to my `videos.insert` - I will get an exception that says I have too much arguments. In other examples that I found on Google(YouTube Data API v3 documentation) was a code example in .NET where the `filePath` was just another parameter for the `videos.insert` but here in Dart it doesn't seem to be the same and I am having a hard time understanding how it actually works.

To be more specific in the YouTube Data API V3 documentation the insert example is the following:

```
youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
```

As we can see its very simple. Now in Dart this is where I am stuck:

```
youTubeApi.videos.insert(video, ["snippet", "status"]);
```

As you can see I added the `video` object, the "`snippet, status"` string list but when I try to add a third argument `fileStream` I will get the "too many arguments" message exception.

This is the `videos.insert` method in Dart:

```
Future<Video> Function(Video, List<String>, {String? $fields, bool? autoLevels, bool? notifySubscribers, String? onBehalfOfContentOwner, String? onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel, bool? stabilize, Media? uploadMedia, UploadOptions uploadOptions})
```

**UPDATE 1:**

When I call the insert.video request nothing happens. Here is my current full code right now:

```
import 'package:googleapis/youtube/v3.dart' as YT;

var httpClient = (await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient())!;
var youTubeApi = YT.YouTubeApi(httpClient);

YT.Video video = new YT.Video();
video.snippet = new YT.VideoSnippet();
video.snippet!.title = "Default Video Title";
video.snippet!.description = "Default Video Description";
video.snippet!.tags = ["tag1", "tag2" ];
video.snippet!.categoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
video.status = new YT.VideoStatus();
video.status!.privacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"

var status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  await Permission.storage.request();
}

Stream<List<int>> stream = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/video.mp4").openRead();
int length = await stream.length;
var media = new YT.Media(stream, length);

var videosInsertRequest = youTubeApi.videos.insert(video, ["snippet", "status"], uploadMedia: media);

videosInsertRequest.timeout(Duration(seconds: 60));
videosInsertRequest.then((value) => {print("THEN")});
videosInsertRequest.whenComplete(() => {print("COMPLETED")});
videosInsertRequest.onError((error, stackTrace) => _handleError());
```

The `Video`, `Media` object are from `googleapis/youtube/v3.dart` package.

I tried so far:

- re-create AVD android phone emulator
- wipe all data
- cold boot the emulator
- added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to `AndroidManifest.xml` - ( I have internet on the emulated device, I can open google/youtube and watch videos etc.)
- disable my VPN
- verify my internet connection
- checked video file on local player - its playable and valid

Other googleapis requests work ex. getting playlists. If I don't set a timeout exception then the request just hangs without any response - not even from Android Studio... what am I doing wrong? My internet connection is solid, cable internet and the AVD emulator device has working internet as well. Again, idk if this is the issue because I get no response from YouTube API no matter how long I wait.

Another part that I suspect is the `length` of the media file where I set it at `int length = await stream.length;` - could please someone confirm that I am doing it the right way here?

These are my scopes:

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[YT.YouTubeApi.youtubeReadonlyScope, YT.YouTubeApi.youtubeUploadScope],
);
```

The app asks to read and manage my YouTube account videos and I grant the request in the android emulator. No issues here.

**UPDATE 2**

If I set `null` to the `uploadMedia` I will get an exception of `Invalid Argument` but the meta data contained in the `video` param will be uploaded to my YouTube account. It looks like its something related with the `uploadMedia` file.

```
var videosInsertRequest = youTubeApi.videos.insert(video, ["snippet", "status"], uploadMedia: null);
```

So with this the new video will be created on YouTube with the title, description etc. but without the actual media file.

**Update 3 - IT WORKS!!!**

I changed 2 things in the above code:

- media file type: I don't know why it didn't wanted to work with mp4 files but with .avi files started working
- media length variable from `int length = await stream.length;` to `int length = await new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/video4.avi").length();`

Here is my full working code with Google Sign In:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/youtube/v3.dart' as YT;
import 'package:extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[YT.YouTubeApi.youtubeReadonlyScope, YT.YouTubeApi.youtubeUploadScope],
);

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Sign In',
      home: SignInDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  GoogleSignInAccount? _currentUser;
  String _contactText = '';
  late Future<YT.Video> videosInsertRequest;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) async {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
      if (_currentUser != null) {
        print("User logged in!");
      }
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleVideoInsert() async {
    var httpClient = (await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient())!;
    var youTubeApi = YT.YouTubeApi(httpClient);

    YT.Video video = new YT.Video();
    video.snippet = new YT.VideoSnippet();
    video.snippet!.title = "Default Video Title";
    video.snippet!.description = "Default Video Description";
    video.snippet!.tags = ["tag1", "tag2" ];
    video.snippet!.categoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    video.status = new YT.VideoStatus();
    video.status!.privacyStatus = "private"; // or "private" or "public"

    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }

    Stream<List<int>> stream = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/video4.avi").openRead();
    int length = await new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/video4.avi").length();
    YT.Media media = new YT.Media(stream, length);
    print("Insert in progress...");
    videosInsertRequest = youTubeApi.videos.insert(video, ["snippet", "status"], uploadMedia: media);

    //videosInsertRequest.timeout(Duration(seconds: 60));
    videosInsertRequest.then((value) => {print("THEN")});
    videosInsertRequest.whenComplete(() => {print("COMPLETED")});
    videosInsertRequest.onError((error, stackTrace) => _handleError());
    print(video.status!.uploadStatus);



  }

  FutureOr<YT.Video> _handleError() async {
    print("Error");
    return new YT.Video();
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignOut() => _googleSignIn.disconnect();

  Widget _buildBody() {
    GoogleSignInAccount? user = _currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: GoogleUserCircleAvatar(
              identity: user,
            ),
            title: Text(user.displayName ?? ''),
            subtitle: Text(user.email),
          ),
          const Text("Signed in successfully."),
          Text(_contactText),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN OUT'),
            onPressed: _handleSignOut,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('UPLOAD'),
            onPressed: () { print("Upload button pressed!"); _handleVideoInsert(); },
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text("You are not currently signed in."),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN IN'),
            onPressed: _handleSignIn,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
        ),
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: _buildBody(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help! I hope it will help someone in the future. Also as a note for the above code to work you still need to configure your project in Google's Console and give the appropriate API's permissions explained here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/google-apis

Comment: Check this official documentation. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert It's just a simple HTTP post request. Check out the python and java code there and check how they are sending it to API you will understand.

Comment: In which package `Video()` class is defined?

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar Video is defined in "googleapis/youtube/v3.dart"

Comment: Ok, then you are probably on right track. You just need to send the actual video to the API check the link above.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found a solution. All I had to do is specify the `uploadMedia:` property name in the parameters and now I am able to add another argument type `Media`

Comment: Almost did it but now my request just hangs :( I updated my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233483/discussion-between-asp1re-and-chirag-bargoojar).